# Asynchronous processing of streaming HTTP with requests / requests_futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I understand how to stream data over HTTP with requests:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
for line in r.iter_lines():
    print(line)
```

I understand how to process a request asynchronously:

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession()
def bg_cb(sess, resp):
    # parse the json storing the result on the response object
    resp.data = resp.json()

future = session.get(url, background_callback=bg_cb)
# do some other stuff, send some more requests while this one works
response = future.result()
```

But I don't understand how to combine the two, that is, how to get callback to my designated function whenever the next line is available from the `r.iter_lines()`:

```
session = FuturesSession()
def bg_cb(sess, resp):
    # parse the json storing the result on the response object
    resp.data = resp.json()

future = session.get(url, background_callback=bg_cb, stream=True)

# do other stuff here
```

The code snippet calls my `bg_cb` function just once, before any data is actually available. Instead, I want `bg_cb` to be called whenever a new line is available.

Comment: instead of `print` you put your callback function ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I edited my last code snippet to clarify my problem. I really can't figure out a way to get a call back from a the `get` request whenever new data is available - rather than just once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pycurl`, like it says in the [docs](http://pycurl.io/):

One example could be:

```
import pyrcurl

STREAM_URL = "whatever/url"

def on_receive (data):
    print(data)

'''We instantiate the Curl object and setoptions so that it gets executed. 
We use the on_receive function so that the stream of data is printed as it arrives the object, which is very cool! 

The perform() operation keeps executing as it is a real time stream of data, not executing the subsequent code UNTIL we set a TIMEOUT option or we sys.exit() it with CTRL+C
'''

conn = pycurl.Curl()
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive)
# conn.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 15)
conn.perform()
conn.close()
```

The `pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION` executes the on_receive function whenever a new data is streamed.

The `pyrcul.TIMEOUT` is used to specify the seconds that `perform()` method will be executed.

Note: the resulting object will be `class <bytes>`, so you will need to make the appropiate processing in the application.